# Asymptotic expression for sum of first n prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Is one known? If not, what are the best known bounds? Is there reason to think that an asymptotic expression is beyond current methods if none exists?

Comment: Maybe $\int_0^n \frac{t}{\log(t)}dt$?

Comment: $$\sum_{k = 1}^n p_k \sim \frac{n^2}{2}\log n$$ since $p_k \sim k\log k$. You can get more terms in an asymptotic expansion if you take a more precise estimate for $p_k$, look up Dusart's bounds for $p_k$ if you're interested.

Comment: Concerning Dusart's bounds suggested by Daniel Fischer see for example <http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434229/is-the-n-th-prime-smaller-than-n-log-n-log-log-n-1-frac-log-log-n-log>

Answer (score 12):

Sinha's paper [On the asymptotic expansion of the sum of the first n primes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1667) gives quite a bit of info including a few bounds and various asymptotic results (including some from Dusart).

The simple one, as Daniel Fischer pointed out, is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n p_k \approx \frac{n^2}{2}\ln n$$

Dusart (1998) showed

$$\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = \frac{n^2}{2}(\ln n + \ln\ln n - 3/2 + o(1))$$

Sinha (2011) showed

$$\sum_{k=1}^n p_k = \frac{n^2}{2}\left[\ln n + \ln\ln n - \frac{3}{2} + \frac{\ln\ln n}{\ln n} - \frac{5}{2\ln n} - \frac{\ln^2\ln n}{2\ln^2 n} + \frac{7\ln\ln n}{2\ln^2 n} - \frac{29}{4\ln^2 n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\ln^2 n}\right)\right]$$

Axler works through a lot of the math behind these in a [June 2016 arXiv paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06874v1.pdf).

I'd also like to note that it is possible to write a prime sum function similar to fast prime count functions.  This gives exact results quite a bit faster than standard sieve+sum code.

For those with a more practical bent, I highly recommend Kim Walisch's [Primesum](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primesum) program and documentation.  It implements the summation using fast combinatorial methods combined with excellent optimization and parallelization.  It has been used to compute exact answers for primes below $10^{24}$ for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it is interesting to see a easy proof of the simplest approximation. From the [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) and the [Abel's summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{k}\sim\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\log\left(k\right)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\cdot\log\left(k\right)
=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\log\left(n\right)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor \left(\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor +1\right)}{t}dt
 $$ $$=\frac{n^{2}}{2}\log\left(n\right)+O(n^{2})
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor$ is the floor function, hence

> $$\color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{k}\sim\frac{n^{2}}{2}\log\left(n\right).}$$

Comment: You are using this question for the first formula, I think : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697098