# if $f(n) \to g(n)$ then $\frac{\sum f(n)}{\sum g(n)} \to 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Say we have some function $f(n)$ that behaves like $g(n)$ for large $n$. It is easier to analyse in general the $g(n)$. Then it seems intuitive to say $$\frac{\sum f(n)}{s_n}\to 1$$ where $s_n= \sum g(n)$ (i.e coming from the asymptotic recipe for $f(n)$). Is this intuition correct? How can one prove/disprove it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think [Stolz-Cesaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) is something like what you're interested in.

Comment: I think you will need to say more about $f$ and $g$ before you can reach any sort of conclusion like that, but as @AntonioVargas pointed out, there are things that can be said in that direction.

Comment: @AntonioVargas many thanks for the hint. I see the solution now :-)

Comment: What does "behaves like" mean here? $f(n)\to g(n)$ is meaningless with the standard usage of limits.

Comment: It won't be true if $g(n)\to 0$, however.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It *can* still be true of $g(n)\to 0$; for instance, if $g(n)\geq 0$ as long as $\sum g(n)$ diverges.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree, I was not so precise in writing. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean $f(n)\sim_{n\to\infty} g(n)$, "i.e." (up to some technicalities if $g$ cancels) $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 1$.

Then this is false:

- take $f(n) = \frac{6}{\pi n^2} + \frac{1}{n^3} $ and $g(n) = \frac{6}{\pi n^2}$. Then 
  $$
  \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)}{\sum_{n=1}^N g(n)}\xrightarrow[N\to\infty]{} 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} \simeq 2.2
  $$
- But this is true if $f(n)\geq 0$ and $\sum_n f(n)$ diverges (which implies $g(n)\geq 0$ and divergence of $\sum_n g(n)$):
  $$
  \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N f(n)}{\sum_{n=1}^N g(n)} = 1+ \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \left( f(n) - g(n)\right) }{\sum_{n=1}^N g(n)}
  $$
  and by theorem s of comparisons, the second term will be $o(1)$ (this last point does require a proof, not very complicated. Let me know if I should include it.)

Comment: It seems the $a_n\sim b_n, \;\; \sum b_n = \infty, \;\; b_n\geq 0 \implies \sum^n a_k \sim \sum^n b_k$ is taught only in French secondary education ...

Comment: That's a shame then... I'd deem that a quite useful result.

Comment: this is a nice result and I did not know it :-/ in fact I am interested in cases where $s_n$ diverges to $+\infty$.

Comment: Do you have any assumption on the sign of $g$? (or its monotonicity?) Otherwise, you can have counterexamples: take $f(n) = (-1)^n+\frac{2}{n}$ and $g(n) = (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$, for instance.