# $\lim_{\,n\to\infty}\frac{S(n)}{n\pi(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, limits, summation, prime-numbers

Let $S(n)$ be the sum of primes less than or equal to $n$. I guess that  $\lim_{\,n\to\infty}\frac{S(n)}{n\pi(n)}$ exists and it's equal to $0$ but I can't prove it .I've begun to doubt it but If my guess is true I want a proof that doesn't use the prime number theorem.

Comment: [The limit is $\frac{1}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693478/asymptotic-expression-for-sum-of-first-n-prime-numbers)

Comment: @DanielFischer Seeing you around is making me  happy.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to express $S(n)$ in terms of $\pi(n)$:
\begin{align}\sum_{p\le n, prime}p&=\sum^n_{k=2}k\,(\pi(k)-\pi(k-1))
\\&=\sum^n_{k=2}(k\,\pi(k)-(k-1)\,\pi(k-1))-\sum^n_{k=2}\pi(k)
\\&=n\,\pi(n)-\sum^n_{k=2}\pi(k)
\end{align}
Now according to the prime number theorem,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\,\,\pi(n)}{\frac{n^2}{\ln n}}=1,$$ and according to the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)
,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum^n_{k=2}\pi(k)}{\frac{n^2}{\ln n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\pi(n)}{\frac{n^2}{\ln n}-\frac{(n-1)^2}{\ln (n-1)}}=\frac12,$$ so we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S(n)}{n\,\pi(n)}=\frac{1-\frac12}{1}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/439305),
$$
\begin{align}
S(n)
&=\sum_{p\le n}p\\
&=\frac12\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log(n)^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Since
$$
n\,\pi(n)=\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}+O\!\left(\frac{n^2}{\log(n)^2}\right)
$$
we have
$$
\frac{S(n)}{n\,\pi(n)}=\frac12+O\!\left(\frac1{\log(n)}\right)
$$