# On the sums of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, distribution-of-primes

It is known that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^np_k \sim \frac12n^2\ln{n}$$
The proof of which I cannot find.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439289/sum-of-the-first-n-prime-numbers) is a related MSE post with an appreciable answer.  Now, I wonder how one might go about finding $f(n)$ such that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^np_{2k+1} \sim f(n)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A_n=\sum_{k=0}^np_{2k+1}$ and $B_n=\sum_{k=0}^np_{2k}$. Then $p_{2k}<p_{2k+1}<p_{2k+2}$ implies
$$B_n<A_n< B_{n+1}$$
and therefore, since $\sum_{k=1}^np_k \sim \frac12n^2\ln{n}$, it follows 
$$2n^2\ln(n)\sim\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}p_k= A_n+B_n< 2A_n< A_n+B_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}p_k\sim 2n^2\ln(n).$$
Hence $\sum_{k=0}^np_{2k+1}=A_n\sim n^2\ln(n)$. Moreover, we have also that $\sum_{k=0}^np_{2k}=B_n\sim n^2\ln(n)$.

P.S. As a reference for $\sum_{k=1}^np_k \sim \frac12n^2\ln(n)$ see [Asymptotic expression for sum of first n prime numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693478/asymptotic-expression-for-sum-of-first-n-prime-numbers)

Comment: Thank you; how did you obtain $2n^2\ln(n) \sim \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}p_k$?

Comment: By your first line, $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}p_k \sim \frac12(2n+1)^2\ln(2n+1)\sim 2n^2\ln(n) $

Comment: What is a more accurate function asymptotic to $\ln(2n+1)$ than $\ln(n)$?  I am not too familiar with big/little-oh notation, so it would be helpful to see how they appear in this function.  Would it be $\ln(n) + o(\ln(2n+1))$?

Comment: We have that $\ln(2n+1)=\ln(n(2+1/n))=\ln(n)+\ln(2+1/n)=\ln(n)+O(1)\sim \ln(n)$. ($O(1)$ means that it is bounded)