# $\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{2k+1}-p_{2k} \sim f(n)$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, prime-gaps

In an [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301544/on-the-sums-of-primes), user [Robert Z](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/299698/robert-z) proved 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{2k+1} \sim 2 n^2\ln n$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{2k} \sim 2 n^2\ln n$$

Yet clearly (the $2k$ is arbitrary here, replace it with $k$ if you feel so inclined)

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{2k+1}-p_{2k} \nsim 0$$

Although by following Robert's method, I am unable to show that the above difference is asymptotic to anything useful. Can a meaningful $f(n)$ asymptotic to the above sum of differences be determined? Meaningful, as in non-constant.

Comment: It's certainly between $2n$ and $2n\ln n$. And the asymptotic should be $ n\ln n$, but that may be difficult to prove....

Comment: presumably there are lower order terms which stay

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst yes, my problem is finding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's reasonable to assume the prime gaps from consecutive even or odd primes should not, on average, be very much different compared to each other, so summing them should give approximately the same values. As such, you get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{2k+2}-p_{2k+1} \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{2k+1}-p_{2k} \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{2k}-p_{2k-1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Actually, as the prime gaps tend to, on average, be growing for larger primes, especially for large enough $n$, you can often replace the $\approx$ with $\ge$ in \eqref{eq1A} to have upper & lower bounds of the middle expression value. Next, let

$$m = \sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{2k+1}-p_{2k} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Then \eqref{eq1A} becomes

$$p_{2n+2} - m - p_2 \approx m \approx p_{2n+1} - m - p_1 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Add $m$ to all $3$ parts and divide by $2$ to get

$$\frac{p_{2n+2} - p_2}{2} \approx m \approx \frac{p_{2n+1} - p_1}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, by the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number) approximation, you have $p_{2n} \sim (2n)\log(2n)$, so you then get

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}p_{2k+1}-p_{2k} \sim \frac{(2n)\log(2n)}{2} \sim n\log(n) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This matches what [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown) says the asymptotic value should be.

Comment: You write: *it's reasonable*. But do you know of any theorem along this line? (It'd be a great theorem to prove otherwise!).

Answer (score 0):

OP requests:   *Meaningful, as in non-constant.*

Let's do it:

$$ p_1-p_0=1\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad \forall_
      {n\ge 1}\,\, p_{2\cdot n+1}-p_{2\cdot n}\ge 2 $$
hence:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\,\,(p_{2\cdot n+1}-p_{2\cdot n})\,\,\ge
     \,\,2\cdot n-1 $$

This has fulfilled the OP's request.

> It seems not easy to improve upon the above inequality meaningfully
>   by **elementary** means. The following equation is a symptom:
>
> $$ p_3-p_2\,=\,p_5-p_4\,=\,p_7-p_6\,=\,2 $$

Comment: I've written "**elementary**" but I don't even know about un-elementary (about **arbitrary** ). Does any of you **?**