# What are the lower and upper bounds for the sum of the first $n$ primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

I am looking for the lower and upper bounds for the sum of the first $n$ primes, $S(n)$ for all $n \geq 2$

I found that $S(n) = \frac{n^2}{2 \log n} + O(\frac{n^2}{\log^2n})$. This is only an upper bound, and also not explicit.

What are some explicit (i.e without asymptotic notation) lower and upper bounds for $S(n)$ that fit all $n \geq 2$?

EDIT

I just found good bounds from this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06874 (Axler 2016):

A lower bound for all $n \geq 2$ And an upper bound for all $n \geq 1897700$.

There is also an upper bound for all $n \geq 6$ (from a different source):

$S(n) \leq \frac{p_n^2}{\log{p_n}} \leq \frac{n^2(\log n + \log \log n)^2}{\log n(\log n + \log \log n -1)}$

and we can refactor it for $n \geq 2$

$S(n) \leq \frac{p_n^2}{\log{p_n}} \leq \frac{n^2(\log n + \log \log n)^2}{\log (n(\log n + \log \log n -1))}+6$

Is there a better upper bound for $n \geq 2$?

Comment: FYI, a related question is [Asymptotic expression for sum of first n prime numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1693478/602049), with the answers also discussing previous papers containing expressions for bounds. Also, an upper bound is discussed in [Sum of the first n Prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/439289/602049).

Comment: You're welcome. As I indicated, the first linked post discussed, in the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1693936/602049), a previous paper by Sinha (link in the answer) which it says "gives quite a bit of info including a few bounds". You will need to reference that paper for the bounds. Also, the second linked post gives an upper bound in the question itself of $\frac{P_m^2}{\ln(P_m)}$.

Comment: Thanks I guess I missed it, will check for more information about it.

Comment: The sum is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A007504 with many formulas and links to the literature.

Comment: Have you had a look at that link, Aladin?

Comment: Yes (and thanks for the reference) but I found only one link discussing bounds. but already found it (it is the one mentioned in the post)